# Cannot open phpmyadmin after xampp installed on ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I start xampp with `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` command but phpmyadmin doesn't work.

[start xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpXuC.jpg)

[phpmyadmin doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvvF6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there are some misconfiguration on phpmyadmin and mysql connection.

Why do we have to install xampp if we can have LAMP instead with much easier way. Install LAMP with these terminal commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

You'll no longer have to start/stop xampp server manually. And you'll have all basic PHP server functionality.

Comment: Do I need uninstall xampp ?

Comment: No you don't. But if the lamp-server works for you. Xampp will be no longer needed :)